# Updating single view on change of a model in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The setup of Backbone:

1 Collection,
3 Models,
1 View for the collection, 
1 View per Model.

HTML:

```
<div id="showit"></div>
```

Template:

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <a class="item" href="#">{{book.name}}</a>
    <br/>
    <span>Liked :{{book.likes}}</span><br/>
</script>
```

Backbone JS:

```
Book    =   Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                name    :   "No Name",
                author  :   "No Name",
                likes   :   0
            }

BookListView    =   Backbone.View.extend({
                        collection  :   BookList,
                        initialize  :   function(collection){
                            this.collection = collection;
                            this.render();
                        },
                        render      :   function(){
                            this.collection.each(function(model){
                            var pustakView = new BookView({model: model});
                            pustakView.render();
                            });                                
                        }                              
});

BookView    =   Backbone.View.extend({
    model       : Book,                
    initialize  : function(){},       
    events      : {"click a.item": "clicked"},
    template    : Handlebars.compile($('#item-template').html()),

    clicked     : function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var likes_count =    this.model.get("likes");
                    this.model.set({likes:++likes_count});
                    this.renderOne();
    },

    renderOne   : function(){
                    var output=this.template({'book':this.model.toJSON()});
                    $(this.el).html(output);                    
    },
    render      : function(){
                    var output = this.template({'book':this.model.toJSON()});
                    $(this.el).append(output);
                    $('#showit').append($(this.el));
     }  
});  

var book1   =   new Book({name:'Awesome Book1',author:"John",likes:10});
var book2   =   new Book({name:'Awesome Book2',author:"Dave",likes:20});
var book3   =   new Book({name:'Awesome Book3',author:"Bill",likes:30});

BookList    =   Backbone.Collection.extend({model:Book});
var myBookCollection    =   new BookList([book1,book2,book3]);
myBookList  =   new BookListView(myBookCollection);
```

So here is a snippet of what it generates on page load:

```
<div id="showit">
    <div>
       <a class="item" href="#">Awesome Book1</a><br>
       <span>Liked:10</span><br>
    </div>
...
...
</div>
```

I am a newbie into world of backbone and trying to implement the basics to apply it into my site. I have referred [this site](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/) for the above implementation. (Well, not exactly as I have customized it for my needs).

The feature I have been trying to implement is that multiple models with same template will load in 1 Collection, clicking on any element in the rendered view of that model has to give me access to that model so that I can re-render the view of the clicked model only.

The above example does the same where in clicking a hyperlink updates the counter called 'likes' and updates the corresponding model view only. As it can be noticed I have not specified an 'el' attribute for the view of each model and so it will be a 'div'.

My Question is whether this method is an efficient method of updating individual views (when model attributes change due to events) or are there any better methods than this? Also I am not sure if having a view for each loaded model will not cause any memory issues (asuuming I have an infinite scroll implemented which keeps on loading the list of Books)

If the above implementation is good enough, I hope it can help other backbone newbies to get up and running with re-rendering model view when model attributes change.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, Backbone views already have a cached version of `$(this.el)` in [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) so you should use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`.

I find that things work better when views only touch their own `el` and leave it up to someone else to put that `el` into the DOM. In your case, that would mean that you shouldn't do this:

```
$('#showit').append($(this.el));
```

in the sub-view, it would be better to say:

```
render: function() {
    var output = this.template({'book':this.model.toJSON()});
    this.$el.html(output);
    return this; // <----------------- this is common behavior, you'll see why in a moment
}
```

and then in the parent view, you say this:

```
el: '#showit',
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
        var pustakView = new BookView({model: model});
        this.$el.append(pustakView.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

The parent adds the child using the child's new return value from `render`:

```
this.$el.append(pustakView.render().el);
// ---------------------------------^^
```

Also note the second argument to `this.collection.each` to make `this` inside the iterator function the parent view.

Now we don't need `renderOne` in `BookView` at all, you can bind `render` to the appropriate event. You can also leave the re-rendering up to Backbone. When you say this:

```
this.model.set({likes: ++likes_count});
```

you will trigger a `'change'` event on `this.model`. If you bind to that in `initialize`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

then Backbone will call `render` for you when the model changes.

Back to `BookListView`. A view's [`initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) will copy the `collection` property out of its options just like it will copy `model`:

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`, `attributes` and `events`.

so your `BookListView` should look more like this:

```
var BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    //...
```

and you should instantiate it like this:

```
var myBookList = new BookListView({ collection: myBookCollection });
```

Notice that I have removed `collection: ...` from the view declaration. The `collection` and `model` properties should be instances and they should be bound per-view-instance so you almost never want `collection` or `model` to appear when defining a view, you only want to see those in the view's argument list when you instantiate a view.

Furthermore, I notice that you're not using `var` to declare your variables. That means that you are creating accidental globals all over the place and that's never a good idea. Always use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare variables so that you can control the scope.

Comment: Implemented all the suggestions offered and was able to see the effect in firebug profiler.
Results: v1 (21.222ms, 2076 calls), v2 (18.671ms, 1614 calls)
v1 (profiler for my original script) v2 (profiler for script with suggested changes)
Firebug Profiler was done for initialization of 'BookListView' with a collection consisting of 10 'Book' Objects.
I see that the performance has increased. Could you also please shed some light on memory issues if there is 1 view per model with an infinite scroll implementation

Comment: One view per model vs one big view shouldn't really have much of a memory impact on its own. If they scroll and scroll and scroll then you'll chew up pretty much the same memory either way.

Answer (score 1):

Changing model attributes within an click handler is okay and very common, but I would suggest keeping your rendering code away from event handlers. Backbone supports event mechanism that can help implementing Observer pattern, so it's unnecessary to explicitly write `renderOne()` everywhere after you change the model.

In your case, `this.model.set({likes:++likes_count})` causes the model sending a "change" message to all views that concerned with it. You can register BookView's `renderOne()` function to this message. Then, if the model changes, re-rendering function will be automatically called.

```
BookView    =   Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  initialize  : function(){
    // if "change" on this model is triggered, call renderOne.
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.renderOne);
    // if the model has been removed from the collection, this
    // view is not needed, call remove.
    this.listenToOnce(this.model, "remove", this.remove);
  },       
  events      : {"click a.item": "clicked"},
  ...    
  clicked     : function(e){
    ...
    this.model.set({likes:++likes_count});
    // this.renderOne(); this line is commented out 
  },
  renderOne   : function(){
    ...                 
  },
  render      : function(){
    ...
  }  
});
```

Besides, View provides `remove()` function to reclaim itself (remove HTML snippet from its parent node, stop listening to the model, etc), but it is the developer's duty to decide when to reclaim. A common time to reclaim View is after the corresponding model removed from the container, or destroyed. You can refer to [Backbone's documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) for these special events.